# can complex numbers be used in Apple metal code?

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line, metal

I'm trying to make a stand alone binary which uses metal for acceleration.  (found a solution in another answer)

I'm trying to compile the metal code and I get an error;

`metal_mandel.metal:24:16: error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'device complex' (aka 'device __Reserved_Name__Do_not_use_complex')`

```
using namespace metal;

///#include <complex.h>


kernel void point_in_mandel(device complex* inC,
                          device complex* inZ,
                          device int* count,
                          uint index [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    // the for-loop is replaced with a collection of threads, each of which
    // calls this function.
    count [index] = 0;

    while(cabs(inZ[index]) < 2.0 && count[index] < 256)
    {
        inZ[index] = (inZ[index] * inZ[index]) + inC;
        count[index] ++;
    }

}
```

I've tried both adding and removing the `include complex` but my head is too sore from looking at this code all day, to work this out further.

Do I just have to implement complex numbers manually?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: You can look into this resource: https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf

Comment: also are you using this: https://github.com/jtbandes/metalbrot-playground/blob/master/Metalbrot.playground/Resources/Shaders.metal ? Maybe complex keyword is not allowed in kernel signature, try renaming your custom struct.

Comment: `complex` is not a custom struct.   I'm using it from here; `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/complex.h` But no mention of it in the MSL.  Looks like I have to write it myself.

Comment: Did you tried adding in linker flag '-lmx'?